# Existence of unknown fields in Python Protocol Buffers v3.5.1 messages

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

The protocol buffers Python message implementation [preserves unknown fields in messages as of v3.5.0](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.5.0).I've noticed I can determine whether there are unknown fields in a particular message using `message._unknown_fields`.

I have two questions:

1. `m._unknown_fields` gives me the values of unknown fields in `m`, but not in any children of `m`. For instance, if `m.a` has unknown fields, they will appear in `m.a._unknown_fields`, but not in `m._unknown_fields`. Is there a way to determine whether there are any unknown fields in a message or any of its submessages? I can implement a walk down the message tree with a `._unknown_fields` query at each node, but this seems like overkill; all I want is to determine whether any unknown fields were encountered during parsing of a message.
2. The `_` prefix to `_unknown_fields` seems to indicate that this is a private/undocumented call. Is there an approved method of determining if there are unknown fields?

Comment: on 1: I think you're going to have to implement your walk

Answer (score 1):

1. To be minimally disruptive, you pretty much have to walk down. Those unknown fields belong quite specifically to the message they are attached to.

   You should also be able to detect if any part of the message tree contained unknown fields by calling `DiscardUnknownFields()` on the topmost message and comparing the `ByteSize()` of the message before and after. If the value decreased, there used to be unknown fields there ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

   This will work equally well with the C++ compiled extension library, which as far as I can tell does not provide the `_unknown_fields` attribute anywhere visible. If you need to keep them and just need to know if they exist, you can use `CopyFrom(...)` and try dropping unknown from the copy.
2. I don't think there is any public API for determining the presence of unknown fields in either the pure-Python or compiled versions of the library. Regardless, the above still works and *is* approved, if a little odd.